# NCMBのビルドエラーが解消出来ない

Tags: swift, xcode

初めて投稿させていただきます。

Buildするとerrorが発生してエミュレータでのテストは出来るのですが、実機でのテストが出来ない状態です。
内容を見ているとNCMBが原因のような気がしますが、どのように対処すればいいか分かりません。
誰かご教示いただけないでしょうか。

```
PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Embed\ Pods\ Frameworks /Users/MyPC/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-fgncbpfcpzoyxmgcemhcwpkaaply/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test.build/Debug-iphoneos/test.build/Script-624B16F1207C06B12FA1DC8F.sh
    cd /Users/MyPC/Folder/test-app
    /bin/sh -c /Users/MyPC/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-fgncbpfcpzoyxmgcemhcwpkaaply/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test.build/Debug-iphoneos/test.build/Script-624B16F1207C06B12FA1DC8F.sh

mkdir -p /Users/MyPC/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-fgncbpfcpzoyxmgcemhcwpkaaply/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/test.app/Frameworks
rsync --delete -av --filter P .*.?????? --filter "- CVS/" --filter "- .svn/" --filter "- .git/" --filter "- .hg/" --filter "- Headers" --filter "- PrivateHeaders" --filter "- Modules" "/Users/MyPC/Folder/test-app/NCMB/NCMB.framework" "/Users/MyPC/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-fgncbpfcpzoyxmgcemhcwpkaaply/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/test.app/Frameworks"
building file list ... done
NCMB.framework/
NCMB.framework/NCMB -> ./Versions/Current/NCMB
NCMB.framework/Resources -> ./Versions/Current/Resources
NCMB.framework/Versions/
NCMB.framework/Versions/Current -> ./A
NCMB.framework/Versions/A/
NCMB.framework/Versions/A/NCMB
NCMB.framework/Versions/A/Resources/
NCMB.framework/Versions/A/Resources/NCMB_Info.plist

sent 9463715 bytes  received 106 bytes  18927642.00 bytes/sec
total size is 9462166  speedup is 1.00
Code Signing /Users/MyPC/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-fgncbpfcpzoyxmgcemhcwpkaaply/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/test.app/Frameworks/NCMB.framework with Identity iPhone Developer: テスト (VE8574GCQA)
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign 9FDB9DCD26910A4AD5893360914595990A947A04  --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements '/Users/MyPC/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-fgncbpfcpzoyxmgcemhcwpkaaply/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/test.app/Frameworks/NCMB.framework'
/Users/MyPC/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-fgncbpfcpzoyxmgcemhcwpkaaply/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/test.app/Frameworks/NCMB.framework: bundle format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0):

- Xcodeを一旦終了して下さい
- デスクトップをクリックして、ファインダーを選択し、コマンドキーとシフトキーを押しながらGキーを押して下さい
- 小さなウィンドウが開くので、そこに`~/Library/Developer/Xcode`と入力してフォルダを表示ボタンを押して下さい。
- 新しく開いたFinderウィンドウに`DerivedData`というフォルダーがあるので、それをゴミ箱に入れ、ゴミ箱を空にして下さい
- Xcodeを立ち上げ、問題があったプロジェクトを再度ビルドしてみて下さい

6/8 追記

- Xcodeの一番左のエリアで、一番上のプロジェクトアイコンを押して下さい
- ソースコード表示だった画面が設定画面に変わると思うので、エリア一番上の`Build Phases`をクリックして下さい
- Copy Frameworks (もしくは自分の付けた名前）でフレームワークをコピーするための設定を行う蘭があると思うので、横向き△をクリックして内容を展開して下さい
- `MCNB.framework` の行の一番右に Code Sign On Copyというチェックボックスがあるので、現在の値から反転してみて下さい
- もしくは、同じく`General`をクリックして、`Signing`のエリアで`Automaticaliy manage signing`にチェックが入っていることを確認して、チェックされていなければチェックを入れて下さい
- `Team` のポップアップメニューが「自分の名前 (Personal Team)」またはAppleから発行された開発者証明書の名前になっているか確認して下さい

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
テスト端末でシュミレータを選択するとビルドエラー解消しましたが、実機を選択すると同様のエラーが変わらず出力される状態です。

Comment: 考えられる対処方法を追記してみました。お時間のあるときにでも確認して見て下さい

Comment: ご教示ありがとうございます。いただきました事を試したのですが、まだ変わらない状態です。